# Prove non-constant rational functions must be decreasing sometwhere

Tags: calculus

How to prove a non-constant rational function $f(x)$ must be decreasing somewhere if $f(x)$ is always positive?

Suppose $f(x)=\dfrac{g(x)}{h(x)}$, if $f(x)>0$, we have $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ must be even degree polynomial functions. Can I prove if $f'(a)=0$ exists, then $f(x)$ must be decreasing somewhere when $x<a$ or $x>a$? If so, how to find $f'(x)$? If not, what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that $f'(a)$ exists everywhere $g(x) \neq 0$ ,and you can find $f'(x)$ by using the quotient rule (which holds for all $x$ with $h(x)\neq 0$) given by $f'=$($\frac {h}{g})'=\frac {h'g-hg'}{g^2}$, and you know $f',g'$ exist, since $f,g$ are polynomials. Then you actually know $f'$ is differentiable , because it will also be a Rational function( and so , in particular, f'is continuous). Then, if $f'(a)<0$ for some $a$ , then you know there is an open set where $f'(a)<0$ , by continuity of $f'$. So all you need to do is show that there must exist some $a$ with $f'(a)<0$.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I actually have no idea how to prove there must exist some $a$ with $f'(a)<0$. Since $f(x)$ is always positive, $h(x)$ and $g(x)$ must be always both positive or both negative. We can let $g(x)=m^2(x)+c$ and $h(x)=n^2(x)+d$ while $c$ and $d$ have the same parity. Then we have $f'(x)=\dfrac{2g(x)g'(x)(h^2(x)+d)-2h(x)h'(x)(g^2(x)+c)}{(h^2(x)+d)^2}$. Since $(h^2(x)+d)^2$ is always $>0$, we need to prove there exists some a such that $2g(x)g'(x)(h^2(x)+d)-2h(x)h'(x)(g^2(x)+c)<0$. I stuck here.

Comment: Are you assuming $f(x)>0$, or are you considering different cases?

Comment: Yes, $f(x)$ is always $>0$ is the condition.

Comment: Thanks; let me give it a try.